# adcenter api keyword performance report soap request error

Tags: xml, soap, soapui

I am executing the following soap request to adcenter api but am getting an error

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header xmlns="https://bingads.microsoft.com/Reporting/v9">
    <Action mustUnderstand="1">SubmitGenerateReport</Action>
    <DeveloperToken i:nil="false">XXXXXX</DeveloperToken>
    <Password i:nil="false">XXXXXXX</Password>
    <UserName i:nil="false">XXXXXXX</UserName>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <SubmitGenerateReportRequest xmlns="https://bingads.microsoft.com/Reporting/v9">
      <ReportRequest i:nil="false" i:type="KeywordPerformanceReportRequest">
        <ReportName i:nil="false">Keyword Performance Report</ReportName>
        <ReturnOnlyCompleteData i:nil="false">false</ReturnOnlyCompleteData>
         <!--Keep these fields if you set the i:type attribute to KeywordPerformanceReportRequest-->
        <Aggregation>Daily</Aggregation>
        <Columns i:nil="false">
          <KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>AccountName</KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>
          <KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>CampaignName</KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>
          <KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>Keyword</KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>
          <KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>TimePeriod</KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>
          <KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>Impressions</KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>
          <KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>Conversions</KeywordPerformanceReportColumn>
        </Columns>
        <MaxRows></MaxRows>
        <Scope i:nil="false">
          <AccountIds i:nil="false" xmlns:a1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
            <a:int>2738383</a:int>
          </AccountIds>
        </Scope>
       </ReportRequest>
    </SubmitGenerateReportRequest>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I getting the following error

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Content-Length: 747 Content-Type:
>   text/xml; charset=utf-8 Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0 X-Powered-By:
>   ASP.NET Date: Thu, 08 May 2014 19:21:21 GMT
>
> a:DeserializationFailedThe formatter threw an exception while trying to
>   deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to
>   deserialize parameter
>   [https://bingads.microsoft.com/Reporting/v9:ReportRequest](https://bingads.microsoft.com/Reporting/v9%3aReportRequest). The
>   InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the
>   object of type
>   Microsoft.AdCenter.Advertiser.Reporting.Api.DataContracts.Request.ReportRequest.
>   The value '' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int32'.'.  Please see
>   InnerException for more
>   details.

Can someone please check this request and tell me what could be wrong with this soap request. I have tried executing it in SOAPUI but could not understand the issue

Arif

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I had to provide the maximum rows value in the below tag

```
<MaxRows></MaxRows>
```

Arif